# Three unit vectors whose sum is zero

Tags: vectors

Let $\overrightarrow a ,\overrightarrow b ,\overrightarrow c $ be unit vector such that $\overrightarrow a  + \overrightarrow b  + \overrightarrow c  = 0$. Which of the following is correct ?

(A) $\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  = \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c  = \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow a  = \overrightarrow 0 $

(B) $\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  = \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c  = \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow a  \ne \overrightarrow 0 $

(C) $\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  = \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c  = \overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow c  \ne \overrightarrow 0 $

(D) $\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b ,\overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c ,\overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow a $ are mutually perpendicular

The official answer is (B).

My approach is s follow

$\overrightarrow a  + \overrightarrow b  + \overrightarrow c  = 0$

$\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  + \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow b  + \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow b  = 0$

$\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow b  =  - \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow b  = \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c $

$\overrightarrow a  \times \overrightarrow c  + \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c  + \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow c  = 0 \Rightarrow \overrightarrow b  \times \overrightarrow c  = \overrightarrow c  \times \overrightarrow a $.

Now I am confused between option (A) and (B) if $\overrightarrow a ,\overrightarrow b ,\overrightarrow c $ are parallel to each other then option (A) is correct or option (B)

Vector being a unit vector plays any vital role in deciding between (A) and (B)

Comment: $c = -a -b$, so $c$ lies in the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$. The only possibility is that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are unit vectors in that  plane and that $\angle ab = \angle bc = \angle ca = 120^\circ$. No two of them can be parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are all parallel to each other then $\vec{b} = k\vec{a} $, $\ \vec{c} = m\vec{a} $ which means that $(1+k+m)\vec{a} = \vec{0} $

We can't have $\vec{a} = \vec{0}$ since $\vec{a}$ is a unit vector. Similarly   we notice that since all three are unit vectors then $k$ and $m$ must be either 1 or -1 so $k + m + 1 \neq 0$ which proves that you can't have three linearly dependent unit vectors that are parallel to each other (try to think of this geometrically - what would the sum of two parallel unit vectors on a plane be?)

Answer (score 3):

(A) would imply the vectors are pairwise parallel or antiparallel, so their sum is of length $1$ or $3$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec a, \vec b$ are parallel, they have the same direction.

Since they are both unit vectors, this implies $\vec a = \vec b$ and $\vec c = -2\vec a$.

But now $|\vec c| = |(-2\vec a)| = 2$, contradicting the fact that $\vec c$ is also a unit vector.

Comment: you could have $\vec b=-\vec a$ too, but now $\vec c$ is null vector.